# How to determine which Node APIs are supported by which version

Tags: node.js

When introducing new modules to a project - as a maintainer - how can you determine which built-in APIs are supported by a particular **Node.js** version? Or the **Node.js** version in which they were introduced?

For example, the [`util.debuglog`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_debuglog_section) API was introduced in `v0.12`, but there is no mention of this in the function-level documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version information is slowly being added to the documentation for various modules. However at the time of this writing, the `util` module does not have this information yet. PRs are welcome of course :-)